# Как передать в sqlldr или sqlplus пароль в котором содержится знак доллара $

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Например, вызываем sqlldr:

```
sqlldr SYSTEM/PA$$WORD control=loader.ctl > output.txt
```

И получаем в ответе:

```
SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Nov 21 17:00:14 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-128: unable to begin a session
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

А если вызывать просто `sqlldr control=loader.ctl` и далее вводить username и password с клавиатуры то все удачно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте двойные кавычки. В sqlplus/sqlldr:

```
SQL> connect SYSTEM/"PA$$WORD";
```

В командной строке:

```
sqlplus SYSTEM/"PA$$WORD"@DATABASE_NAME
или
sqlplus SYSTEM/\"PA$$WORD\"@DATABASE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

В командной строке оболочек (*shell*) некоторые символы, в данном случае `$` (доллар), имеют специальное значение, т.е. программы получат как аргумент совсем не то, что ожидалось:

```sh
$ echo "pa$$word"
pa591word
```

В POSIX оболочках, например *Bash*, экранируйте симвоолом `\` или одиночными кавычками:

```sh
~$ sqlldr system/pa\$\$word@dbsrv/service_name control=loader.ctl

~$ sqlplus -l system/'pa$$word'@dbsrv/service_name
```

В командной строке инструментов, SQL*Plus или `SQL*Loader, задавать пароль можно как есть:

```
~$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL> conn system/pa$$word@dbsrv/service_name
Connected.
```

PS: Решение в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/166372/217579) ТС отметил как принятое, но оно нигде работать не будет.